# Routing Table implementation : linked list vs array

Tags: data-structures, routes, arm

I am trying to implement my own routing protocol over BTLE PHY and link layers to have a multi-hop link for BTLE radio. I am using Cortex-M0 processor for the same. My routing table structure is basically as follows:

```
|Neighbour Address| Info about Link quality | Possible Destination Addr|
```

The neighbour address will have address of immediate neighbour and possible destination addresses field will have addresses of destinations (within one hop) that can be reached from that particular neighbour (the routing only supports 2-hop communication). In short, the possible destinations will have entries of the elements which are in Neighbour address of the neighbour.

I am implementing this in C with CodeSorcery Toolchain Bare for ARM. So, for building a routing table, should a linked list be used or an array? Using array will be easier than implementing a linked list but then, the size of array will be predefined and limited. Plus, when initializing, it will eat up all the space dedicated to it. Will it be actually good to reserve space for routing table so that it will not cause memory problem later? Or should it be linked list which is more flexible in data allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best data structure is to do both.  You can allocate address tables in 'blocks'.  Each block will contain multiple routing table entries and the next pointer.  After you fill up the block you can allocate the next block and fill it's address in the previous block next pointer.

Such structure gets both of both worlds,  you get the speed of simple table scan and flexibility of the linked list.

How large your network is going to be?  For very large networks,  simple table will be a performance bottleneck,  so you should consider using a hash table of prefixes so that you don't need to traverse the entire table to find a particular neighbor.